# passing id of current user rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Super simple question... Im playing around in the rails console and am trying to pass the user id to a user_id column.

```
u = User.create(:name => "foo", :email => "bar")
Card.create(:user_id => u)
```

allways gives me `user_id 1` no matter what the actual id is of the user.

I have my cards belonging to user and my user having many cards... but at the moment I have to explicitly use `Card.create(:user_id => u.id)`

I know I'm missing something painfully obvious here... I'm presuming declaring something in the controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
u = User.create(:name => "foo", :email => "bar")
Card.create(:user => u)
```